# How set in the option the equal right padding or margin in the header for IOS and Android in React Navigation?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I should implement an equal gap for both sides and both platforms IOS and Android. For the right side, I did this with help of a **minus margin, positive padding, and Platform**.

```
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    contentStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
    headerBackTitle: 'Back',
  }}
>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="TempusHomeScreen"
      options={{
        title: 'TEST',
        orientation: 'portrait',
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          headerRight: () => <SupportButton />,
        }}
      component={Home}
    />
```

src/components/SupportButton/**SupportButton.tsx**

```
  return (
    <View style={[styles.buttonOuterContainer, style]}>
      <Pressable>
        <View style={styles.buttonInnerContainer}>
          <SupportIcon />
        </View>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
};

export default SupportButton;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonOuterContainer: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'red',
    paddingRight: 16,
    marginRight: Platform.select({ ios: -20, android: -16 }),
  },
  buttonInnerContainer: {
    width: 21,
    height: 22,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'green',
  },
});
```

But how fix the left side ???

[image]

Comment: you can use this lib it makes your UI responsive https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-size-matters

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem only with the component SupportButton which I use in headerRight, by using different paddingRight for different Platforms.

```
export default SupportButton;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonOuterContainer: {
    paddingRight: Platform.select({ ios: 13, android: 18 }),
    marginRight: Platform.select({ ios: -20, android: -16 }),
  },
  buttonInnerContainer: {
    width: 21,
    height: 22,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

[image]